# LDA model with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, lda

I have some problem with inferring topic distribution for a new document.
Actually, I'm using Spark 2.2.0, and i have already trained LDA model
`val lda = new LDA().setK(5).setMaxIterations(24)`

How can I infer topics for a new document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the `LocalLDAModel` can score against new documents, so need to convert your model to that first:

```
val localLda = lda.toLocal
```

then for a single document:

```
val document: Vector = ???
localLda.topicDistribution(document)
```

or multiple documents:

```
val documents: RDD[(Long, Vector)] = ???
localLda.topicDistributions(documents)
```